# HTML hyperlink to retrieve data from a single mysql record

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

This code was working perfectly and is retrieving data from my Mysql database. I had a little issue with the path pointing to this script. I am having issues  with the hyperlink with the href code line. I have a field in my database that is labled fulltext . I am trying to create a script that allows me display the content of fulltext (`echo "{$row['fulltext']}.";`) when I click on the Read More button. The hyperlink should be populated with the `echo "{$row['title']}.";`
       What mistake am I making by inserting `a href="fulltext.php?=$row['fulltext']`

fulltext.php contains  `htmlspecialchars($_GET["fulltext"]);`

```
<table>
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'myusernm';
    $dbpass = 'mypwd';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT title, introtext, created, created_by, catid FROM      mydb_items';
    mysql_select_db('muslimtimes360');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<tr>'; echo '<td>'; echo '<span class="post-date">'; echo   "{$row['created']}."; echo '</span>'; echo '</td>'; echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'; echo '<h2 class="blog-post-title">'; echo "{$row['title']}."; echo '</h2>'; echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'; echo '<p>'; echo "{$row['introtext']}."; echo '</p>'; echo '</td>'; echo '</tr>';

        echo '<p>'; echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'; echo '<a href="fulltext.php?=$row['fulltext']>'; echo '<input type="button" value="Read More" />'; echo '</a>'; echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="blog-meta">';
        echo '<img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />';
        echo '<tr>'; echo '<td>'; echo '<h4 class="blog-meta-author">'; echo "{$row['created_by']}."; '</h4>';
        echo '<span>'; echo 'Category:'; echo "{$row['catid']}."; echo '</span>'; echo '</td>'; echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }

    echo "";

    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: [Create *page break* or *read more* tag with php](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/135652-create-page-break-or-read-more-button-in-your-page/)

Comment: whats in "fulltext.php" ?

Comment: You're not selecting the `fulltext` column in your query, what is `$row['fulltext']` supposed to contain?

Comment: still using mysql_connect?? try mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you aren't putting the variable into the string properly. Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. And the quotes inside the array index are terminating the string after `echo`.

Second, you need to give a parameter name before `=` in the URL.

Third, you were missing the closing double quote for the `href` attribute.

```
        echo '<td>'; echo '<a href="fulltext.php?id=' . $row['fulltext'] . '">'; echo '<input type="button" value="Read More" />'; echo '</a>'; echo '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
echo '<a href="fulltext.php?=$row['fulltext']>'
```

to

```
echo '<a href="fulltext.php?'.$row['fulltext'].'">'
```